# Are virtual functions less likely to cause stack overflow?

Tags: c++, memory, embedded, virtual-functions

In an interview I was asked if function parameters are located in the stack or the heap. I'm pretty sure this was being given as an example to illustrate how recursive functions are avoided due to stack overflow risks at embedded memory scales. However, it seemed like a trick question because I had been reviewing virtual functions, which allow [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch).

After searching around [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459450/how-are-function-arguments-stored-in-memory), it seems that the memory location for a plain old regular function's argument(s) is implementation dependent.

Other answers pretty much say the same thing for virtual functions -- no guarantees are made for the how virtual function arguments are implemented in memory.

So I'd like to understand:

1. How and where (stack? heap? smattering of both?) do runtime function implementations come in?
2. Without knowing anything about what the ABI says, would this be useful to know about/ a good place to find this kind of information or is there a better place to look? Beyond specifications, is there any experimental data that lets us "see" how memory works on average, in practice?

Also, first-post hello!

Comment: Not an expert but I can't imagine many implementations allocating memory from the HEAP to store parameters when all it needs to do is move the stack pointer and plop them right down or move them into registers. I don't know why dynamic dispatch would change how parameters were handled.

Comment: If you want to see how it works in practice, most implementations provide a way to save the intermediate assembly code. You can then see how function arguments and local variables are implemented.

Comment: C++ doesn't care about _any_ of this. It guarantees your program's observable semantics; nothing more.

Comment: It is a trick question, some interviewers like that approach.  They like to see you squirm and observe only the way you talk yourself out of it, the technical answer doesn't matter.  Okayish when it is like a PM position you applied to.

Comment: @Galik thanks, that clarified things a bit and is not far from my guess: that _eventually_ this data would be in a stack frame. I still don't totally understand why this is implicitly less of an issue for the rest of the memory, but some of the answers seem like they might touch on that. But I think you've shown that my confusion begins at how these are implemented in practice, as Barmar said-- I'll try looking at the intermediate code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How and where parameter/return values are passed around is defined by the function's calling convention, `virtual` has no effect on that at all.  Some calling conventions use the stack only, while other conventions use a mix of stack and CPU registers.  But never the heap.

The only thing `virtual` does is dictate how the function address is determined, and what value to pass in its hidden `this` parameter. But parameter values (including `this`) and return values are passed around based on the calling convention only.

On 32bit, the two calling conventions that are standardized across implementations are `__cdecl` and `__stdcall`.  Other calling conventions are implementation-defined, like `__fastcall` and `__thiscall`.

On 64bit, the ABI defines a single calling convention that all implementations must follow. 32bit calling conventions are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a `virtual` function non-virtually. Hence, it's not the definition of the function, but the type of the call which determines the virtual-ness. Therefore, it's practically impossible to have different conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Where parameters and return values go are the preserve of the calling conventions, there are many calling conventions and they all have nuances.
In 64 bit x86 computing there are only 2 calling conventions worth thinking about Microsoft and SystemV.
Both calling conventions are designed to pass as much in registers as you possibly can. Off the top of my head that is 4 integer parameters and 4 float paramaters. There are special cases but in general anything beyond this will be pushed to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of "calling a function" is inherently connected to the stack. The calling convention can move some of the arguments to the registers, and passing parameters indirectly (by pointers or references) can reduce the amount of actual data being passed, but the return address still has to be pushed on stack.

The legitimate way to have no stack impact is to inline the function, which one may argue is not exactly a "function call" per se, and is becoming progressively harder to guarantee nowadays - that is, the decision is up to the compiler.
It's possible to inline the tail recursion, turning it into infinite loop and thus not running out of stack for eternity.

Finally, the only way `virtual` is connected to any of this is that dynamically linked calls are much harder to inline - they need to be devirtualized first, which is still not impossible.

The overall conclusion seems to be "if there is any connection at all, it's in favor of non-`virtual` functions".

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. And if this way around "all roads lead to the stack" is in the gray area for what is a function call, I could see why it was just assumed.